# Flux through off-centered hemisphere

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the flux of the vector field $\vec V = r \cos \theta \hat r + r \sin \theta \hat \theta + r \sin \theta \cos \phi \hat \phi$  through the spherical surface of inverted hemispherical bowl of radius R,resting on the xy plane and centered at the origin.

I use Physicist's convention here. So $\theta$ is polar angle and $\phi$ is azimuthal angle.

How do I find the limits of the parameters for the surface integral as well as the area element? And also how do I find the normal vector of the surface in spherical coordinates?